# On Click i want to show button and again on click i want to hide a button

Tags: javascript

i am not sure, what i should be using, please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn2').hide()
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
   $("#btn2").show()
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btn1">BTN 1</button>
  <button id="btn2">BTN 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of toggle
https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn2').hide()
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
   $("#btn2").toggle()
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btn1">BTN 1</button>
  <button id="btn2">BTN 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn2').hide()
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
   $("#btn2").toggle()
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btn1">BTN 1</button>
  <button id="btn2">BTN 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide it in HTML or CSS and then [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) it

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    $("#btn2").toggle()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btn1">BTN 1</button>
  <button id="btn2" hidden>BTN 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `$("#btn2").toggle()` instead of `$("#btn2").show()`, or you can add an if condition to check whether the button is visible or not.